Movie where everyone is killed by the end
I'm looking for a movie that may be from the 1990s and is set in the American Midwest. Definitely with cowboy boots. I thought it was a Coen brothers film but it isn't.
It has a super-tight narrative. By the end all characters have been killed and no one would know the deaths were connected (like in Burn After Reading).
I think the final death was in an office — not a corporate office, more like attached to a car sales business. It was during daytime and there was a desk and filing cabinets.
I think there was some suspicion about adultery. Money and private detectives were involved (but it's not Blood Simple, I've just watched that).
This all sounds like a zillion films. I will post more if I recall any more. 
I thought it might have Holly Hunter in it, but I've checked, and none look familiar. Any suggestions? 

Fargo has a carsales man as the protagonist and it is a Coen movie. Not sure if everyone is killed though.

Thanks ElDuderino. Not snowy Fargo. A hot weather film. I don't think it's Cohen brothers (although I did think this for a long time).

Longshot, because the last death doesn't match, but it wasn't Last Man Standing by any chance?

I haven’t seen this film in a while—and I’m not too sure about the cowboy boots—but the adultery, private detectives and the fact every major character seems to die at the end seems to point to the Coen brother’s 2001 film, The Man Who Wasn’t There:




Could this be El Mariachi? It had a Cohen brothers feel to it, definitely had cowboy boots and lots of other characters getting killed. 
It has been a while since I saw this, but parts of it seem to fit your description.
No big name actors were in the original but there were also two sequels (Desperado and Once Upon a Time in Mexico) that had Antonio Banderas as the title character.
